# Cannot assign variable from data.tf to variables.tf file

Tags: azure, terraform

New to terraform, and have been building out the infrastructure recently.
I am trying to pull secrets from azure key vault and assign the keys to the variables.tf file depending on the environment(dev.tfvars, test.tfvars, etc). However when I execute the plan with the tfvar file as the parameter, I get an error with the following message:

> Error: Variables not allowed

Here are the files and the relevant contents of it.

variables.tf:

```
variable "user_name" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}
```

data.tf (referencing the azure key vault):

```
 data "azurerm_key_vault" "test" {
  name                = var.key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
  name         = "my-key-vault-key-name"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.test.id
}
```

test.tfvars:

```
user_name = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value}" # Where the error occurrs
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? And if so is there another way to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform a `variable` can be used for user input only. You can not assign to them anything dynamically computed from your code. They are like read-only arguments, for more info see [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables) from the doc.

If you want to assign a value to something for later use, you must use `locals`. For example:

```
locals {
  user_name = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value
}
```

Local values can be changed dynamically during execution. For more info, see [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals).

Answer (score 1):

You **can't create dynamic variables**. All variables must have known values before execution of your code. The only thing you could do is to use local, instead of variabile:

```
locals {
  user_name = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value
}
```

and then refer to it as `local.user_name`.